# Get screen (View) black pixels fast and efficiently

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I was searching in already asked questions, but all of them are just describing how to get pixel colour of UIImage (which I already did but is not the best solution in my case).

I want to check all pixels of my screen and get number of black pixels or almost black (very dark) pixels. I know how to check how dark a single pixel is - with checking if RGB (255) values of pixel selected is less than 10 or something. But I don't know how to check the full amount of pixels of a UIImage in a fast and efficient way.

So I want to check all pixels of my screen and get the number of them. Later in my app I do it again and than compare amount of black pixels before and after some events.

Is there any fast solution to get them?

Comment: Slightly improved the readability, tried to explain the real problem a bit clearer.

Comment: You can take a "snapshot" of the screen, and now the problem is the same as getting the pixels of an image.

Comment: @matt I figured out! Thanks anyway.. It was exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

It was "snapshot" that I was searching for if anyone else will have some similar situation.
I took a snapshot:

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
 [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 UIImage *original = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

And then searched for black pixels in it:

```
    width = (int)original.size.width;
    height = (int)original.size.height;


    CFDataRef imageData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(original.CGImage));


    const UInt8 *pixels = CFDataGetBytePtr(imageData);
    UInt8 blackThreshold = 5; // or some value close to 0 - dark pixels
    int bytesPerPixel = 4;
       for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
           int pixelStartIndex = (x + (y * width)) * bytesPerPixel;

        UInt8 redValue= pixels[pixelStartIndex];
        UInt8 greenValue = pixels[pixelStartIndex + 1];
        UInt8 blueValue = pixels[pixelStartIndex + 2];

if(redValue < blackThreshold && blueValue < blackThreshold && greenValue < blackThreshold) {
            /// count black pixels ore something else you want to do
        }
    }
}
```